# Brightcove: Hide control on HTML5

Tags: html, mute, brightcove

Is it possible to hide the controlbar in HTML5 player for a brightcove video?
I'm using the SmartPlayer API to do so in flash I use the following callback on the templateLoadHandler:

```
Player.prototype.adaptPlayer=function(experienceID)
{
    var experience=instance.getExperience(experienceID),
        modVideo=experience.getModule(APIModules.VIDEO_PLAYER),
        modExperience=experience.getModule(APIModules.EXPERIENCE);

    if(experience.type==='flash') {
        modExperience.getElementByID("videoPlayer").getControls().setIncludeInLayout(false);
        modVideo.mute();
    }
};
```

The HTML5 Player is rendered in iframe. Someone could tell me how to hide controls here?

THANK YOU